# How do I align a footer to the bottom of a flexbox "cards?"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a series of "cards" that I've set up via flexboxes. I have a footer that I want to add to each that "pins" itself to the bottom of each box (not sure if I'm using the right terminology there).

However, I want it to pin to the bottom no matter the length of the content within the card. In other words, I'd like the footer to snap to the bottom based on the card that has the longest content within the row.

This fiddle hopefully explains what I mean. The card with minimal content should have the footer in the same spot as the card that has more content:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xMWYjR

Here's the code:

```
.card-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 0 30%;
    border: 1px solid #323232;
}

.card-footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-top: auto;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

---

```
<div class="card-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Content</p>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <p>Footer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Content content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content content</p>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <p>Footer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
    .card-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .card {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex: 0 0 30%;
        border: 1px solid #323232;
    }

  .card * {
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    text-align:center;
  }

    .card-footer {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        margin-top: auto;
        align-self: flex-end;
    }
```

```html
<div class="card-wrapper">
<!-- first card start -->
    <a href="#" class="card">
      
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Content</p>
            <div class="card-footer">
               <p> Footer</p>
            </div>
    </a>
    <!-- first card end -->
    <a href="#" class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Content content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content content</p>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <p>Footer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code:**

Description: I update a simple code where tell the `.card-content` class display flex, flex column, and it's also height 100% on the instant parent. I also remove a little code form `.card-footer`  **align-self: flex-end;** property.

Actually, your code is fine but your parent (.card-content) not same height parent. I just solve it.

```css
.card-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  border: 1px solid #323232;
}
    
.card-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.card-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="card">
        <div class="card-content d-flex flex-column">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Content</p>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <p>Footer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Content content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content content</p>
          <p>Content content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content contentContent content content</p>
            <div class="card-footer mt-auto">
                <p>Footer xx</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**Thank you**